# Склонение топонимов с родовым словом (В городе Чайковский / Чайковском)

Tags: грамматика, склонение, согласование, топонимика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сказать:
соревнования в городе Чайковск**ий** или в городе Чайковск**ом**. Я придерживаюсь второго варианта, но организаторы соревнований в г. Чайковском говорят, что верный вариант: в городе Чайковск**ий**. Кто из нас прав?

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: в городе Чайковском

Русские географические наименования, употребленные с родовыми названиями типа город, хутор, деревня, поселок, станица, село, поселок, река и выступающие в роли приложений (стоящие после названных слов), склоняются, если являются топонимами русского (а также славянского) происхождения или представляет собой давно заимствованное и освоенное русским языком наименование.

Подробнее можете ознакомиться здесь: [Географические наименования в сочетании со словом город...](http://gramma.ru/SPR/?id=3.3)

Comment: Серж, в статье по вашей ссылке "на горе Железной, до острова Каменного, у сопки Высокой, до озера Щучьего, на станции Тихорецкой" - это разговорные варианты, а в общелитературной речи они не склоняются.

Comment: Вера, обратите внимание: в статье говорится: ***Не склоняются:***

а) названия станций, местечек, курортов, аулов, кишлаков, застав:

Comment: В ответе же говорится о склонении:  городов ,хуторов, деревень, поселков, станиц, сел, , рек.

Comment: Да, это фактор, говорящий об малой известности топонима.

Comment: Если употребляется слово "город", это уже своего рода формальное представление следующего за этим словом топонима, которое при необходимости можно трактовать и как сокращение от "город под названием...". Поэтому даже такие наименования, как Москва, не застрахованы от склонения, тем более, что города с таким названием есть и в Америке.

Comment: И ещё бывают названия, которые нелишне приводить для справки в именительном падеже: Колпино, Вышний Волочёк - люди, связанные с этими местами, никогда в сочетании с "городом" не слоняют этих названий. Более того, Колпино или Комарово местные жители и региональные газеты не склоняют и без упоминания типа населённого пункта - несмотря на известность общих грамматических рекомендаций. Таковы региональные речевые традиции.

Comment: Alex_ander, честно говоря, не понял ваш первый пост о " формальном представлении" и  " ... Москва, не застрахованы от склонения"?

Comment: Названия на на -ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно, не склоняются с родовым словом.

Comment: Я о том, что слово "город" употребляется в таких выражениях ещё и с информативной функцией, чтобы адресат знал, как пишется или произносится наименование в именительном падеже. Если для одних названий это прямая необходимость, для других  (включая "Москву") нельзя запретить отказа от склонения. Названия на "-ово и пр." только циркуляром можно заставить склоняться: для Москвы и центральной электронной прессы склонение характерно, для многих других обширных мест - нет. Нельзя, находясь вблизи Петербурга, Колпино, Комарово или Купчино приравнивать "Бородину" :)

Answer (score 3):

1) **Склоняемость топонима зависит от ряда факторов**: стиля речи (деловой, научный, общелитературный, разговорный), от известности топонима (станица или город), от наличия родового наименования (Чайковский или город Чайковский), от грамматической формы топонима (существительное или прилагательное, прилагательное склоняется чаще ).

Вот примеры: Климат Грозного умеренно-континентальный. Лето в Грозном жаркое и длительное. Информация о городе Грозный в Википедии. Карта города Грозного.

Грозный - название большого города, топоним известный. При отсутствии родового наименования склоняется, при наличии родового наименования используются оба варианта.

2) Теперь о Чайковском. Город менее известный, также в этом случае действует дополнительный фактор: совпадение фамилии и названия города, поэтому требуется точность названия. С другой стороны, это грамматическая форма прилагательного, склонная к изменению по падежам. Факторы противоречивые, поэтому и решение неоднозначное.

Поэтому можно предложить следующее: в Чайковском, в городе Чайковский (деловой и общелитературный стиль), в городе Чайковском (общелитературный и разговорный стиль).

Comment: Вера, а на чем основано ваше утверждение, что город менее известен? Сам топоним русского происхождения, вряд ли его не знают в России. И еще: на основании чего вы делаете вывод, что  в городе Чайковский деловой и общелитературный стиль?

Comment: Несклоняемость города была нормой, если бы могла возникнуть путаница: т.е.при склонении сложно будет восстановить исходную форму: городе Видном – это город Видный или город Видное?).( Город Видное - не склоняется.

Comment: В Интернете можно найти несклоняемый вариант Москвы. Это же не значит, что город не склоняется.

Comment: Серж, я говорю про влияние различных факторов и считаю, что  допустимы оба варианта. Организаторы используют деловой стиль (в городе Чайковский), в СМИ можно встретить оба варианта,  обычные люди говорят "в городе Чайковском". Все правы.